# Changing values in array based on values in another array

Tags: php, arrays

Here's an example in plain english of what I am trying to achieve: 
if the number given is 4, then I want to add 1 to every value that is equal to or less than 4 into the corresponding index of another array. (hope that makes sense)

So my first array looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 6 [2] => 7 [3] => 4 [4] => 3 [5] => 2 [6] => 9 [7] => 8 [8] => 1 [9] => 10 [10] => 11 [11] => 12 [12] => 13 [13] => 14 [14] => 15 [15] => 16 [16] => 17 [17] => 18 )
```

The second array looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 [3] => 4 [4] => 4 [5] => 5 [6] => 4 [7] => 4 [8] => 5 [9] => 4 [10] => 4 [11] => 5 [12] => 5 [13] => 4 [14] => 4 [15] => 4 [16] => 3 [17] => 3 )
```

And I am wanting the second array to look like this (after adding 1 to every value below 4 in the first array) so after the addition it would be

```
Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 [3] => 5 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 4 [7] => 4 [8] => 6 [9] => 4 [10] => 4 [11] => 5 [12] => 5 [13] => 4 [14] => 4 [15] => 4 [16] => 3 [17] => 3 )
```

In which index 3,4,5,9 have changed.

Comment: How is the first array used in all of this? Shouldn't index 8 (instead of 9) be updated?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for [array_map](http://php.net/array_map)

```
function increase( $m, $n )
{
  if( $m < 4 )
  {
   return $n+1;
  }
  return $n
}

$arr1;
$arr2;

print_r( array_map("increase", $arr1, $arr2 ) );
```

Note: this will return a new array.

Answer (score 1):

**Using an `array_walk`**

```
array_walk($arr2,function(&$v,$k) use($arr1) { if($arr1[$k]<=$v){ $v=$v+1;} });
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/127923)

#### [or]

**A simple `foreach` will do**

```
foreach($arr1 as $k=>$v)
{
    if($v<=$arr2[$k])
    {
        $arr2[$k]=$arr2[$k]+1;
    }
}
print_r($arr2);
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/127917)